# dropping tables with bigger size

Tags: mysql

We have a mysql database with a size of 2 TB, in which we have for to five big tables ranging from 110GB to 350GB. When we try to drop these tables the mysql goes to the defunct mode and hangs in that state for a long time. Is there a solution to drop these tables without mysql hanging. We have a machine which has a memory of 122GB and swap of 60 GB. We use an InnoDB Engine Hope the information suffices kindly help us with this issue.

Comment: Table engine?  InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: The table engine is InnoDB

Comment: Might be better addressed in DBA SE.

Answer (score 1):

You can try if your MySQL server supports and/or behaves better in your case with setting `innodb_lazy_drop_table=1` in your `my.cnf` file.

This option works for older MySQL versions, my understanding is that the option got removed in the newer versions and the innodb_lazy_drop_table behavior was made the default one.

Comment: We tried the same in the version 5.6.13 , we think that the option has been depriciated

Comment: That is actually a Percona/XtraDB-only variable. See my response on http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84275/30545